# Draw function timer openframeworks

Tags: c++, openframeworks

How can I, using the draw() function of openframeworks, draw a square - ofRect (x, y, w, h) for x in x seconds?

I know it is possible since the draw uses fps but I do not know how to manipulate in order to do what I want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to interpolate based on time, not frame count using [ofGetElapsedTimeMillis()](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/utils/ofUtils.html#show_ofGetElapsedTimeMillis)

Another is to use a tweening/animation addon. You can find quite a few on [ofxAddons](http://ofxaddons.com/) in the animation section

Answer (score 2):

You could do that in the simplest way:

```
int x = ofGetElapsedTimeMillis();
int y = 10;
int w = 100;
int h = 100;
ofDrawRectangle(x, y, w, h);
```

Note that in OpenFrameworks you should use ofDrawRectangle, [it is different](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/what-the-difference-between-ofrectangle-ofdrawrectangle/25942) from ofRectangle.

If you want to reach more adivanced animations, I would recommend you to use [ofxTweenzor addon](https://github.com/NickHardeman/ofxTweenzor), where you can manipulate variables in a period of time like this:

.h file:

```
#include "ofMain.h"
#include "ofxTweenzor.h"

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{
public:
    void setup();
    void update();
    void draw();

    float x1;
};
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "testApp.h"

void ofApp::setup() {
    Tweenzor::init();
    float initialX = 0.f;
    float finalX = 900.f;
    float delay = 0.0f;
    float durationInSeconds = 1.f;
    Tweenzor::add(&x, initialX, finalX, delay, durationInSeconds );
}
void ofApp::update(){
    Tweenzor::update( ofGetElapsedTimeMillis() );
}
void ofApp::draw() {
    int y = 10;
    int w = 100;
    int h = 100;
    ofDrawRectangle(x, y, w, h);
}
```